# git -log -1 --format=%ci shows nothing (w/o --format does) - what's the problem?

Tags: git, github

I'm in the root-folder of a repo and can do `git log -1` and it shows the most recent commit-message with author and date. `git status` confirms that the repo is up to date with the remote origin/master and that the working tree is clean.

However, `git log -1 --format=%ci` shows nothing. ([%ci](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emciem) = "committer date, ISO 8601-like format)  The same with other formats, like [`%aN`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emaNem), [`%cn`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emcnem) or [`%as`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emasem).

What's the problem?

P.S: I'm running this on W10 inside [TakeCommand](https://www.jpsoft.com) with git version 2.26.2.windows.1

Comment: `git log -1 --format=%ci` shows the expected output (for me `2020-04-28 13:37:28 +0000`) on a repo I have here. What's your `git --version` ? Maybe try to double-quote your format.

Comment: What command-line interpreter (shell) are you using? Does it treat `%` specially?

Comment: Thanks Torek - your question led me on the right track: TakeCommand indeed was tricked by the % - I had not thought about that! If you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is used by Windows to access variable's values, e.g. `%USER%`. Because the variable `%ci` does not exist, it will be replaced with an empty string and your format becomes `--format=''`.

Double the percent sign to get a literal percent:

```
git log -1 --format=%%ci
```